# Convert NSMutableArray to a NSSet with the same order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsset

How can I do that programatically?

I am told that this is the way to do it but the `NSSet` has a different order.

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:theArray];
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use an NSSet when order doesn't matter...

Answer (score 11):

If you want order, you'll have to use an NSOrderedSet.

```
NSOrderedSet *set = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:theArray];
```

Comment: Also be sure this is really what you want.  NSOrderedSet is primarily used with CoreData, and while it can be used elsewhere usually NSArray is going to work just fine for you.  http://nshipster.com/nsorderedset/

Comment: Yeah, the main reason to use an ordered set would be that the entries would be uniqued (duplicates removed), but you would still maintain the order of the remaining items.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about the order, you probably do not want to use an NSSet.

Answer (score -1):

There is the solution for Swift 3 :

```
let mutableArray : NSMutableArray!
// Use type NSObject or any custom type
let set = NSSet(array: mutableArray as NSArray as! [NSObject])
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this is going to help in populating the NSSet with an ordered element structure?

Comment: In my case, the order in NSMutableArray is preserved after the convertion on NSSet

Comment: But exactly I just want to understand the mechanism behind that. Because its unusual for a guarantee of order when we are populating NSSet form contents of NSArray. So is populating from NSMutableArray different from that populating from NSSet and if it is then why ?

Comment: Some times order is different. This is not guaranteed.